# How do i "run" a dbunity test?

Tags: dbunit

I am relatively new on unity testing and  just started working with dbUnit.

I wrote a test class, along with the test methods.

However, I have't figured out yet how to "run" my test case class. How can I do that? I mean, how do I execute my test methods and collect the results?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First of all look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716990/5719185 - it is how to prepare dbUnit tests.

And you also need to mark folder with tests, but before this look here (about project structure): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161314/5719185

After this you can choose *Run* in the tests class (right click in your class), or you can execute your tests with Maven, for example with clean-install.